# Update record in table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've added a column in the Review table. Now I would like to update the UserId in Review with the respective UserId in the Users table. When I use the command below I received this error

> The multi-part identifier "t1.UserID" could not be bound

. Here is the statment:
 :

```
UPDATE AT.dbo.Review
SET t1.UserID = t2.UserID
FROM AT.dbo.Review t1
JOIN AT.dbo.Users t2 ON t1.LastName = t2.LastName
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Alias `t1` instead of `AT.dbo.Review`:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.UserID = t2.UserID
FROM AT.dbo.Review t1
    JOIN AT.dbo.Users t2 ON t1.LastName = t2.LastName
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81370/1)